# Multiple character replacements in JS - how to stop replacements on previous results within the same function

Tags: javascript

I have a ( probably very unclean) script that I intend to convert letters put into a text field into html image tags with corresponding pathways. I know there are probably easier ways of doing this, PHP for example however I am using it as a bit of an experiment to familiarise myself further with JS/Jquery. I have overcome a few obsticles to get where I am now as most of this is new ground for me.

In some cases the letters will have multiple images associated with them that will be selected at random so there are a couple of lines included which do this. These are fine however, the issue comes with the section of code that replaces the letters from the text field with the text and variables that make up the image tag. Whilst they work fine individually, when I want to convert multiple letters the replace overwrites instances of that letter in the previously generated image tag. Any ideas can I stop this? I've tried shifting the points at which the script occurs around but it seems the whole thing is somewhat fragile and haven't been able to create a workable solution.

Code in question:

```
        // replace all instances within variable to generate thumbs
        final_result = result.replace(/a/g, str_start+chosen_folder+"a"+random_variation+str_end)
                             .replace(/e/g, str_start+chosen_folder+"e"+random_variation+str_end);
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/N77wZ/

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do only a single replace:

```
final_result = result.replace(/a|e/g, str_start+chosen_folder+"$&"+random_variation+str_end);
```

Comment: Nailed it buddy, I spent ages trying to get it into a single replace. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I have a bit of an issue with this -- There is only a variant on some of the letters so I need to be able to specify which letters are assigned random variations. I think this factor is how I ended up with the original code.. any thoughts?

Comment: You still can build the regex dynamically.